# Im using Replit to create a simple music bot on discord.py yet it keeps giving me an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

The Code

```py
voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels,name='CBT')
voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients,  guild=ctx.guild)
await voiceChannel.connect()
      
ydl_opts = {    
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key':'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec':'mp3',
        'preferredquality':'192',
    }],
}
    
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
        os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
```

I think it gives me a issue here

```
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3'))
```

The error message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means that the `discord.utils.get()` call is returning `None`. The `Client.voice_clients` attribute is a list of [`VoiceProtocol`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#voiceprotocol) objects. (The actual voice connections are [`VoiceClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceClient) objects, though.) The `ctx.guild` attribute ([`Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#guild) object) is a different data type than the items of `Client.voice_clients`, so `discord.utils.get()` will always return `None`.

I think you would have to use a `for` loop to iterate through each voice connection and check if the guilds match:

```py
connection = None
for vconn in client.voice_clients:
    if vconn.guild == ctx.guild:
        connection = vconn
        break

assert connection is not None
```